# Construction of B+ trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

Suppose I am asked to construct a B+ tree, of:

```
i) n = x. 

ii) order = x.

iii) degree = x.

iv) p = x.
```

What should the no. of keys, and pointers that each node can contain, in each of the above cases?

Comment: what is n and what is p?

Comment: @beerbajay Not a homework. For the purpose of understanding. Even if it was one, am not asking you to draw the tree for me.

Comment: @izomorphius: Not sure. That's what the question papers say.

Comment: cs.sjsu.edu/~lee/cs157b/B_Trees_And_B__Trees.ppt check out those lecture slides. n may be the number of keys stored in a node, where you would then have n+1 pointers. Order or Degree may refer to height, but I really don't know. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @JustinDanielson: Thanks. I myself do not know. Found them in question papers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In B+ tree, **Order** denotes Maximum number of child pointers for each internal node, i.e. if Order of a B+ tree is m, then each internal node can have at most m children (subsequently, m-1 number of keys) and at least *CEIL*(m/2) number of children pointers (Except root).

For **Degree** of B+ tree, from [this](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs327/chapter7.pdf), I got the information that if d is the degree of a B-Tree, then each node can contain upto 2d items (keys). Now, both B tree and B+ tree are [Multiway Tree](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cis680/cis680Ch12.html), and hence, I suppose definition of degree will not change. Check the $LINK given as Comment also which indicates same fact.

For n, as JustinDanielson mentioned, it might be total number of keys stored in the node, for which number of children pointer would be n+1 (=x+1 for your question)

Comment: $LINK : http://classes.cec.wustl.edu/~cse241/handouts/btree.pdf
Don't have enough reputation to insert more than 2 links directly, sorry about that.